# Android Studio : emulator errors with service manager

Tags: android, macos, logging, emulation, manifest

I am working on a project which builds and runs properly, using an emulator Pixel 2 API R. I can run my app and interact with it, but I automatically get these errors logged multiple times (they reload every few seconds):

```
? E/servicemanager: Could not find android.hardware.power.IPower/default in the VINTF manifest.
? E/perfetto: r_api_deprecated.cc:216 Tracing session failed
? E/iorapd: Prebuilt compiled trace doesn't exists. file_path: /product/iorap-trace/projectname.compiled_trace.pb
? E/RemoteAugmentedAutofillService: Bad service name for flags 1048704: com.google.android.as/com.google.android.apps.miphone.aiai.app.AiAiAugmentedAutofillService
```

I've tried looking for the device manifest.xml (as the most recurring error message indicates the VINTF manifest does not include some sort of information on the emulator's hardware), but have failed.

I apologise in advance if information is missing, I simply do not know what is of importance here and what is not.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated on what could be causing this.

Comment: Update : after cold booting emulator and most importantly filtering error messages to "Show only selected app", all of the messages 'dissapear'. They are technically still present so if anyone is aware of why that would be greatly appreciated though !